# How do I correctly use square bracket with cdata

Tags: javascript, cdata

This is how my code gets shown in my developer console (Chrome):

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <!&#091;CDATA&#091;
function hidden(){ 
    document.getElementById("test123").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
} 

document.getElementById("test123").addEventListener("click", hidden);

var banner =document.querySelectorAll('.contactBanner1');
for(var i=0;i<banner.length;i++){ 
    banner&#091;i&#093;.addEventListener('mouseover',hidden,false); 
}
// &#093;&#093;></script>
```

This is the error I get now: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

How do I correctly use the **`[`**?

Comment: Assuming you're entering them as `<![CDATA[` & `//]]>`, it works fine for me upon [inspection](https://jsfiddle.net/o7pLvb89/). You running th eoutput through a parser/encoder of some kind?

Comment: using an external js file would bypass these document-based encoding issues.

Comment: @BradChristie Sorry I don't really know what you mean, my wordpress site automatically adds the `<![CDATA[` & `//]]>` and I don't know how to use it. So I ran into this error.

Comment: why would wordpress (invented 2003) add CDATA trash that hasn't been needed since 1998?

Comment: I'm creating the normal `<script>` tag and the next time I open it there automatically is the `CDATA`..

Comment: @dandavis: Technically speaking "needed" vs. "required to be syntacially valid" are two different things. If you want your XHTML passing validation (pre-HTML5) these were used frequently.

Comment: @BradChristie: if XHTML were the target here, it should encode the "<"...

Answer (score 1):

Back when XML was all the rage, people spent a lot of time thinking about their XHTML and XML being parsed by a single XML parser. As such, the XHTML needed to pass XML validation.

But, a problem that can be encountered is when that XHTML includes JavaScript and that JavaScript contains, say, a < meant to mean less-than.

In HTML, XHTML and XML the < means beginning of a start or end tag.

To prevent this, it was recommended that scripts in XHTML have their content marked as Character Data, so that if/when the XML parser got to it, it would effectively ignore special symbols like < (among others).

So, scripts should have been written as:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[ 
           // Inside the CDATA < gets ignored


  //]]>
 </script>
```

Your code doesn't follow this, instead you are providing the Unicode characters for [ and ].

And, lastly, if you are not worried about your JavaScript being parsed as XML, you can just write the more modern version:

```
 <script>


 </script>
```